# Onmouseover firing two events on IE

Tags: jquery, html, onmouseover

I have a problem trying to have a single onmouseover event fire in IE, I have a banner with multiple brands and made a map object for each brand section to fire an event that changes the whole banner and put on a new banner of the brand that was hovered on with the other brands smaller and the function triggered removes the map object and embed the new map object using Jquery append function. everything works fine on firefox and chrome except on IE, it seems to be triggering two events everytime i hover on a section of the brand. Can someone please let me know why IE is firing two events onmouseover instead of 1.i'm sorry for not putting the sample code it seems like there is a problem with Stack not loading the JavaScript file that includes the FCK editor menu's.

Thanks
D

Comment: really can't help if there is no code nor examples for us to view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You clearly have a lot of additional code going on and it's a little hard to figure out the problem.

However, I've experience a number of issues with IE8 kicking off a second event for the object you have extended with JavaScript. Perhaps it might be useful to see if this works.

```
<a href="" onclick="javascript:yourCall('Whatever');return false;" />
```

The

```
return false;
```

JavaScript statement kills off any default event that might be firing.

Answer (score 0):

without your code it is difficult to say whats wrong is going on.

i had tried a sample onmouse event in ie8 it works fine following is a small code snippet which shows an alert event onmouseover it fires only once

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

</head>
<body>

<form name ="subscribe" > 
  <input type="text" name="name" id="txt_name" value="name" onmouseover="alert('hi');">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

can you show some code snippet so that we can understood whats the problem is: